# Closures & async node.js functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, closures

All,

Trying to get my head around closures in a node.js context (async calls).

I have the following code:

```
timer = setInterval(pollOID, 1000);

function pollOID() {
    for (channel in channels) {
        session.get({ oid: channels[channel].oid }, function (varbinds) {
               console.log("The " + channels[channel].name + " is " + varbinds);
        });
    }
}
```

The code polls a router for SNMP data each second using a loop in the setInterval callback to query the router for several SNMP entities. The session.get function has an async callback to process the results from the router.

The SNMP bits are working fine, my question is about how to persist the value of the loop variable channel inside the session async callback.

I get the following results:

```
The Download Attenuation is 7.5
The Download Attenuation is 361600
The Download Attenuation is 60
```

So the loop variable channel is changing for each call to session.get as the function is returning the correct value from the router. My problem is that channels[channel].name uses the current value of channel which by the time the callback has returned the loop has ended and channel is 2 (the third loop, which is the name string "download attenuation"). So I need to persist the value of channel inside the session.get callback to the value it was when the callback is called so the correct channels[channel].name is used in the session.get callback.

I know I have to use a closure for this but after trying a number of different approaches I can't get it working properly. Any clues to point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a simple closure to hold on to a local copy of `channel`.

```
 function pollOID() {
    for (channel in channels) {
      (function(channel){
        session.get({ oid: channels[channel].oid }, function (varbinds) {
               console.log("The " + channels[channel].name + " is " + varbinds);
        });
     })(channel);
  }
```

Or you can also use bind to pass in the argument, but the context will change inside the callback though.

```
for (channel in channels) {
    session.get({ oid: channels[channel].oid }, (function (channel, varbinds) {
           console.log("The " + channels[channel].name + " is " + varbinds);
    }).bind(this, channel));
}
```

And as you guessed your issue is due to accessing `channel` in the callback which is a shared variable and by the time the callback is invoked your for loop would have run through and channel will be holding the last `key` enumerated from `channels`.

Comment: Thank you PSL. The first suggestion with the closure didn't work as 'channel' didn't persist with the original value called, but the second suggestion with the bind did. I'm not sure why the first suggestion isn't working as I thought of that as well and from my (limited) understanding of closures it should.

Comment: @deandob That should have worked, try this way as well. http://jsfiddle.net/pRLVC/ You can use the same concept in your code.

Comment: I find it less confusing to declare a local variable inside the loop block, and use that in the closure body: `var currentChannel = channel;`, then use currentChannel in the closure. But the `(function(a){/*...*/})(a);` pattern is so common in JS these days, it's worth getting used to.

Comment: Ed, that should work as well, but like PSL's first suggestion on the 'classic' closure it doesn't. I have it working with the bind but I still would like to know why the closure isn't working, at least so I can validate my understanding of closures. I'll work on it tomorrow. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I get the same strange behavior in Node 10.  The values in a closure don't seem to "stick" when the callback is invoked by an async function.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async), and this simplifies control flow which can improve readability as more async calls are introduced.

```
function pollOID() {
    for (channel in channels) {
        (function(channel){
        session.get({ oid: channels[channel].oid }, function (varbinds) {
           console.log("The " + channels[channel].name + " is " + varbinds);
        });
    })(channel);
}
```

becomes

```
function pollOID() {
    var log = function(channel, cb){
        session.get({ oid: channel.oid }, function (varbinds) {
           console.log("The " + channel.name + " is " + varbinds);
           cb(); // Moves onto next element in channels when cb is called
        });
    };
    var allDone = function(err, result) {
        // all tasks are complete
    };
    async.each(channels, log, allDone);
}
```

`async.each` will run in parallel so if it needs to be in order, use `async.eachSeries` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I assume the new ES7 async function could also be used.