# Handle queries inside loop in node.js

Tags: node.js

In the following code, the val variable value keeps changing due to asynchronous behavior and generates unexpected output i.e. before connection query for first loop is finished, var variable according to second loop and generates wrong output.What is the best way to handle queries in loop that avoid idiosyncrasies caused by asynchronous nature.

```
    var output = [];
    for ( var j = 0; j < someArr.length ; j++ ) {
         val = someArr[j];//some manipulation of someArr[j]
         connection.query( "select id from someTable where someCol = ?",val, function(err, rows, fields) {
             if ( err ) {
               console.log( err );
             } else {
               output.push( rows[0].someVal );//push query output to this variable
             }
       });
    }
```

console.log( output );//should contain output for all queries.

Comment: You want to be looking up "closures". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505082/closures-async-node-js-functions

Comment: what's i ? And why isn't output initialized ?

Comment: As javascript is asynchronous the variable is missing scope in the loop till it gets response from the query. So, using "let" instead of "var"  in for loop may solve the issue. As, let will be scoped inside the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a closure to generate a temporary scope

```js
var output;
    for ( var j = 0; j < someArr.length ; j++ ) {
         tVal = someArr[j];//some manipulation of someArr[j]
         (function(val){
           connection.query( "select id from someTable where someCol = ?",val, function(err, rows, fields) {
               if ( err ) {
                 console.log( err );
               } else {
                 output.push( rows[0].someVal );//push query output to this variable
               }
           });
         })(tVal);
    }
```

### Theory

#### Execution Context

*JavaScript is a single threaded language, meaning only one task can be executed at a time. When the JavaScript interpreter initially executes code, it first enters into a global execution context by default. Each invocation of a function from this point on will result in the creation of a new execution context.*

#### The Scope Chain

*For each execution context there is a scope chain coupled with it. The scope chain contains the variable object for every execution context in the execution stack. It is used for determining variable access and identifier resolution.*

### Explanation

The anonymous function help us to create a new scope "blocking" the value of `tVal` because when is executed a new `scope` is added to the `scope chain` containing `val` value.
This new `scope` is a **child** of the **parent** `scope` in wich the `for loop` is executed, when the cycle continues `tVal` change but `val` is contained in the **child** `scope` and is safe from the variation.

Comment: This is a really good answer, but I still recommend researching closures to fully understand how it affects variable scoping in javascript.

Comment: Using `someArray.forEach(function(val) { ... });` should also work

Comment: This is called Immediately-invoked function expression. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 3):

The best & standard  way to use loop & inside the that execute query is use **async.eachSeries**.

So using **async.eachSeries** it will execute one by one in series & once foreach complete you can use callback.

Ref : http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

```
var async = require('async');
var output = [];
connection.query('SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 10',function(error,results,filelds){
    if(error) throw err;

    async.eachSeries(results,function(data,callback){ // It will be executed one by one
            //Here it will be wait query execute. It will work like synchronous
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM tablename  where id = 1',function(error,results1,filelds){
                if(error) throw err;

                output.push(results1[0].id)
                callback();
            });

    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(output); // Output will the value that you have inserted in array, once for loop completed ex . 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
    });


})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try **"let"** instead of **"var"** This might work

```
var output = [];
    for ( let j = 0; j < someArr.length ; j++ ) {
         val = someArr[j];//some manipulation of someArr[j]
         connection.query( "select id from someTable where someCol = ?",val, function(err, rows, fields) {
             if ( err ) {
               console.log( err );
             } else {
               output.push( rows[0].someVal );//push query output to this variable
             }
       });
    }
```

Comment: This was real easy and real quick. I was working on this for quite some days and didn't knew it was that easy.