# Handle queries in a loop in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

My questions is an extension of the following post:
[Handle queries inside loop in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891317/handle-queries-inside-loop-in-node-js)

```
var output;
for (var j = 0; j < someArr.length; j++) {
  tVal = someArr[i]; //some manipulation of someArr[i]
  (function(val) {
    connection.query("select id from someTable where someCol = ?", val, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        output.push(rows[0].someVal); //push query output to this variable
      }
    });
  })(tVal);
}
```

Now I want to put the whole code into a function and return output. But when I tried it returned an empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn each `query` into a `Promise`, and then return the `Promise.all` on the array of Promises. No need for that ugly `for` loop closure, just use `.map` instead:

```
function getAllQueries(someArr) {
  const allPromises = someArr.map(val => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query( "select id from someTable where someCol = ?",val, function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      else resolve(rows[0].someVal);
    });
  }));
  return Promise.all(allPromises);
}
```

Consume it with `.then`:

```
getAllQueries(['foo', 'bar'])
  .then((responses) => {
    console.log(responses);
  });
```